# EC2 AMI instance is resetting folder permission everyday

Tags: amazon-ec2, chmod, amazon-ami

I have a log folder `/var/www/app/logs/` in an EC2 AMI instance. My PHP aplication is writing logs there, however every day I must logon and do chmod in order to avoid the error message that the folder is not writable:

`$ sudo chmod 7777 -R /var/www/app/logs/`

For some reason the instance this permissions are reset every morning automatically by some unknown process. Is there a way to make this change permanently?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some log rotation rules set up for this directory, which might be responsible for the permission change.

And, don't set the permissions to `777`, definitely. Either change the owner of the directory to your application user, or add your application user to a group which has write permission to the directory.

Comment: Yeah, exists a daily log, but the permissions and user group is assigned to the log parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether is the best solution, but solves my problem. Edit the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file and change:

```
User apache
```

By:

```
User ec2-user
```

Then restart the webserver.